# Why is Escape key not working in tmux?

Tags: keyboard, tmux

If I hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> to leave Alsamixer, or to enter vi-mode in zsh, nothing happens.

How can I get <kbd>Escape</kbd> working in tmux?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a binding in my `~/.tmux.conf` which was causing the problem:

```
bind-key -n C-[ swap-window -t +1
```

It looks like I cannot bind anything to <kbd>Ctrl-[</kbd> because that is needed to transmit the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key.